# Nested RecyclerView scrolls to the first item on NotifyItemChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have vertical `RecyclerView` for scrolling group of items and horizontal `RecyclerView` in each `ViewHolder` in order to scrol items inside of these groups. They are populated from database. Whenever item content is changed (user tap something or new data come from network) it is written to database and then `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called for the group cursor. I check if it is the same group in `onBingViewHolder()` and update items only if it is. But horizontal `RecyclerView` is scrolled anyway to the first item.

How could I prevent this behavior and why does it happens ?

BTW I'm writing result of this check in 'onBindViewHolder()` to the log and I can see that it is the same item.

Thanks.

Comment: I had similar issue with a horizontal ListView inside `ListView`. I used to save scroll position in the adapter or somewhere. I think I added a onScroll listener or something.

Comment: yeh, that's what I'm going to try right now. Did you managed to figure out what caused this behavior ?

Comment: `ListView` and `RecyclerView` reuse its cells. So when it scrolls away, it's scroll position is lost. And when it is scrolled in back into view, you see it happen like this.

Comment: Yes but problem is that it happens when i do not scroll them at all.

Comment: Could you put some screenshots/dummy picture of your `RecyclerView`? I'm not sure what else the problem could be than what I said so far. :|

Comment: the problem was that `RecyclerView` creates new `ViewHolder` in order to perform animation. `setItemAnimator(null)` solved my problem.

Comment: Post it as an answer then! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RecyclerView` creates new `ViewHolder` in order to perform animation. `setItemAnimator(null)` solved my problem.